# How to extend the expiry time of Firefox's DNS cache

Tags: firefox, dns, dns-cache

Mozilla Firefox's `about:networking#dns` page lists DNS cache entries. I noticed that some of those entries have low expiry times, such as 60 seconds. Is there a way to make Firefox force the minimum expiry time to be e.g. 10 minutes, so that Firefox wouldn't have to make DNS queries so often?

In other words, if a DNS cache entry initially had an expiry of less than 10 minutes, I want Firefox to override the expiry such that the expiry becomes 10 minutes. Is there a Firefox setting to do this?

I am using Firefox 102.8.0esr (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04.5.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there a way to make Firefox force the minimum expiry time to be e.g. 10 minutes

Try this:

1. Type `about:config` in the address bar and press Enter/Return. Click the button promising to be careful or accepting the risk.
2. In the search box above the list, type `dns` and pause while the list is filtered
3. Change `dnsCacheExpiration` to 600.

Reference: [Network.dnsCacheExpiration - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dnsCacheExpiration)

Comment: I noticed that there is also `network.dnsCacheExpirationGracePeriod`. How does `network.dnsCacheExpirationGracePeriod` differ from `network.dnsCacheExpiration`?

Comment: I can't find any official docs for this. You would have to look at the source code.

Comment: `network.dnsCacheExpiration` does not seem to have any effect if I am using "DNS over HTTPS" in Firefox.